# Subtracting Datetime in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Sql view Im trying to write and I'd like to be able to take my DateTime Field (called OrderDate) and then subtract it from the current Time (GetDate()) to show me how long its been in days since the OrderDate. Can someone help out?

Thanks

Comment: What type of database server are you using?

Comment: Which SQL database do you use?

Comment: MSSQL, MySql, what are you using?

Comment: Since `GETDATE` is used, I am assuming SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using SQL Server, since you mention the T-SQL `GETDATE()` function.

For calculations on differences between two date, use the [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, OrderDate, GETDATE())
FROM myTable
```

Comment: I get a weird number 4325 when I do the query. SELECT     TOP (100) DATEDIFF(day, OrderDate, GETDATE()) AS Date
FROM         dbo.MyTable

Comment: @gabrielVa - What does `SELECT GETDATE()` return? What are the top OrderDate fields like?

Comment: @gabrielVa - Is it possible that the OrderDate is 4325 days ago?

Comment: It Returns the current Date and Time, 2011-03-29 16:24:13.700

Comment: The OrderDate is 1999-05-26 00:00:00.000

Comment: @gabrielVa - And the order date of the row that returns this result?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, that looks like about 4325 days ago. The number it is returning is correct.

Comment: @gabrielVa - 12 years * 365 days a year = 4380 days. Looks about right to me.