# SQL Current month/ year question

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a table that has the month and year broken down, for example field called Month has the number 7 in it (this month) and the Year field has 2011. Theres also additional months years, etc. How can I query this to show just the current year, month?

Comment: What type of database is this?

Comment: @Abe Miessler: I'm tagging as SQL Server because all the OP's previous questions either use SQL Server syntax, or have accepted answers that do.  And the OP states to target 2005+ in comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478386/subtracting-datetime-in-sql-query

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY`  instead of `DATEPART`.
*(at least in SQL Server 2005/2008, I'm not sure about SQL Server 2000 and older)*

I prefer using these "short forms" because to me, `YEAR(getdate())` is shorter to type and better to read than `DATEPART(yyyy, getdate())`.

So you could also query your table like this:

```
select *
from your_table
where month_column = MONTH(getdate())
and year_column = YEAR(getdate())
```

Answer (score 10):

This should work for SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE month = DATEPART(m, GETDATE()) AND
year = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work in MySql

```
SELECT * FROM 'my_table' WHERE 'month' = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND 'year' = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: You should mention which database this is for

Comment: You version is the same as mine? Why do I need to mention a db? :s

Comment: Will this work on Oracle, DB2, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Paradox, MS-SQL Server? Any of these? All of these? None of these? Some of these?

Comment: Sorry now I understand, you mean what SQL implementation is this for. Should work on MySql 5.1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Select *
from some_table st
where st.month = to_char(sysdate,'MM') and
    st.year = to_char(sysdate,'YYYY');
```

should work in Oracle. What database are you using? I ask because not all databases have the same date functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CMonth int=null
DECLARE @lCYear int=null

SET @lCYear=(SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()))
SET @CMonth=(SELECT  DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score -3):

**select *
from your_table
where MONTH(mont_year) = MONTH(NOW())
and YEAR(mont_year) = YEAR(NOW());**

Note: (month_year) means your column that contain date format. I think that will solve your problem. Let me know if that query doesn't works.

Comment: You've added nothing to the accepted answers from 3+ years ago, and in fact your answer doesn't address the schema in the OP.